# angular 1.5 get scope date from transcluded element in component *NOT directive*

Tags: scope, components, angularjs-ng-transclude, transclusion, angularjs-1.5

I have component that implements logic with transclude

How can i get component scope

`<confirm-button>
    <md-button ng-disable="$ctrl.checkSomeInsideComponentScope()">
      i'm transcluded button
    </md-button>
  </confirm-button>`

NOTE: transclusion uses transclude slots

Thank you